# inject Database Context into Custom Attribute .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, attributes, entity-framework-core

I'm creating ASP.NET Core 3.1 app, using SPA for front end. So I decided to create custom Authentication & Authorization. So I created custom attributes to give out and verify JWTs.

Lets say it looks like this:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AuthLoginAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
    {
        //Checking Headers..            
            
        using (var EF = new DatabaseContext)
        {
            user = EF.User.Where(p => (p.Email == username)).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(
            "AccessToken",
            AccessToken.CreateAccessToken(user));
    }
}
```

Everything was Okay, but my `DatabaseContext`, looked like this:

```cs
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{        
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }      
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("ConnectionString");
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

I wanted to take Connection string from Appsettings.json and maybe use Dependency injection. I
Changed Startup.cs to look like this:

```cs
//...
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{            
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(
        options => options.UseMySQL(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString"]));
    services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(
        typeof(HMACSHA256_Algo), new HMACSHA256_Algo(Configuration)));
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
    });
}
//...
```

Changed Database Context class to this:

```cs
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; } 
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ///..
    }
}
```

In Controllers I injected DB context and everything works. It looks like this:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("API")]
public class APIController : ControllerBase
{
    private DatabaseContext EF;
    public WeatherForecastController(DatabaseContext ef)
    {
        EF = ef;            
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/API/GetSomething")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Something>> GetSomething()
    {
        using(EF){
           //.. this works 
        }
    }
}
```

But my custom Attribute doesn't work no more. I can't declare new Database context, because it needs `DatabaseContextOptions<DatabaseContext>` object to declare, so how do I inject DBContext to Attribute as I did to Controller?

This doesn't work:

```cs
public class AuthLoginAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private DatabaseContext EF;
    public AuthLoginAttribute(DatabaseContext ef)
    {
        EF = ef;
    } 

    public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
    {
        using(EF){
           
        }
    }
}
```

this works with controller, but with attribute complains about there not being constructor with 0 arguments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you can do is utilize the RequestServices:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AuthLoginAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var dbContext = context.HttpContext
            .RequestServices
            .GetService(typeof(DatabaseContext)) as DatabaseContext;
        
        // your code
    }
}
```

If you allow me to add two comments to your code:

1. Try not to use `async void` because in the event of an exception you will be very confused what is going on.
2. There is no need to wrap injected DbContext in a using statement like this `using(EF) { .. }`. You will dispose it early and this will lead to bugs later in the request. The DI container is managing the lifetime for you, trust it.

Comment: Thanks for anwser. I think it`s okay to use async void in some cases like event handelers. About the second comment thanks, dint knew that

Comment: Should i use 'using' if i get dbcontext from requestservices, like in your anwser ?

Comment: No, you shouldn't put a using statement there too, it's still created and managed by the DI container, we are just asking for the instance explicitly.

Comment: To add simple detail to awnser, you should also type cast it, because requestservice returns object with type object, so you cant access its methods.